# UNKNOWN Check Multiple Metrics

Tags: apache, nagios, ganglia

My ganglia-services.cfg

```
define command {
  command_name  check_ganglia_multiple_metrics
  command_line  /bin/sh /var/www/html/ganglia2/nagios/check_multiple_metrics.sh 
host=$HOSTADDRESS$ checks='$ARG1$'
}

define service {
  service_description   Check Multiple Metrics
  use                   generic-service
  check_command         check_ganglia_multiple_metrics!disk_free,less,10:cpu_numm
,less,8
  host_name             localhost
}
```

but I'm getting an error
[image]

which is exactly the same in command line.
My nagios.log is OK.

When I run `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`
I'm getting

```
  [Mon Oct 26 09:33:54 2015] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for 'EET/2.0/no DST' instead in /usr/share/ganglia/host_view.php on line 117
  [Mon Oct 26 09:37:19 2015] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /
    [Mon Oct 26 09:38:01 2015] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
```

Any help what's the error here?

Comment: The `check_multiple_metrics.sh` script will essentially call: `curl -s http://localhost/ganglia2/nagios/check_multiple_metrics.php?disk_free,less,10:cpu_numm,less,8` So what output do you get when you run that from the command line?  Do you have an apache `error_log`? Have you checked it for errors?  Locations vary depending on the system, but you can try `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: @JoeYoung I updated my question. Thank you

Comment: And the output from the curl command?

Comment: The same status information @JoeYoung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution. When I changed, in the host definition of the localhost.cfg in /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects, the address from the default 127.0.0.1 to my node's address it started running correctly.